# Search recursively for files with certain ending, avoiding SVN folders

Tags: java, io, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

I want to search for files with its name ending in "_1.xml" into a folder (UNIX filesystem, I'm searching into /home/myuser/myfolder/). I would like to avoid svn folders: I don't know if they can give me errors, that's why I want to avoid them. If you asure me they are safe, I don't mind about them.

My code is the following one:

```
/**
 * Searches associated XML file "WHATEVER_id.xml" given an id
 * 
 * @param id
 *            notam id
 * 
 * @return absolute path to XML file
 * 
 */
public String getXMLFileFromID(final int id) {
    String path = null;
    File root;
    try {
        root = new File("/home/myuser/myfolder");
        String[] extensions = {"xml"};
        boolean recursive = true;
        try{
            Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(root, extensions, recursive);

            for(Iterator<File> iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ){
                File file = (File) iterator.next();
                if(file.getName().endsWith(Integer.toString(id) + ".xml")){
                    path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTPDatabase.class).info("getXMLFileFromID : Found associated XML file in " + path);
                    return path;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTPDatabase.class).info("getXMLFileFromID : Unable to find XML associated to id " + id);

    } catch (DatabaseException e) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTPDatabase.class).info("getXMLFileFromID : DatabaseException : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return path;
}
```

Also have tried with FilenameFilters like this:

```
        File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(Integer.toString(id) + ".xml");
            }
        });
        if(matchingFiles.length == 1){
            path = matchingFiles[0].getAbsolutePath();
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTPDatabase.class).info("getXMLFileFromID : Found associated XML file in " + path);
        }
        else{
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTPDatabase.class).info("getXMLFileFromID : Unable to find XML associated to NOTAM id " + id);
        }
```

Any way I'm getting exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directoy,
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.validateListFileParameters (545)
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(521)
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(691)
     at com.core.ftp.FTPDataBase.getXMLFileFromID(227) (that's the FileUtils.listFiles 
line)

     ...
```

Any help?

Comment: Don't you want to consider using `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` instead of doing it all by yourself? Also check `org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.FileFilterUtils.makeSVNAware`.

Comment: full stack trace whould be much nicer. ` Parameter 'directory' is not a directoy, at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.validateListFileParameters (545)` is within external library, and the root cause must be in your code calling that method. So that's why full stack trace is important

Comment: @adarshr if you look the code, you will see I am using FileUtils. If I am doing wrong, please provide an answer and correct me. About the SVNAware I have read and tried: same results. Also, I'm afraid I cannot use parameters as recursively=true if I use the SVNAware call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried yet, but the following snippet should suit your needs:

```java
public List<File> search(File root, int id) {
    List<File> found = new ArrayList<File>();
    if (root.isFile() && root.getName().endsWith("_" + id + ".xml")) {
        found.add(root);
    } else if (root.isDirectory() && !root.getName().contains("svn")) {
        for (File file : root.listFiles()) {
            found.addAll(search(file, id));
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Calling:

```java
List<File> found = search(new File("/home/myuser/myfolder"), 1);
```

Comment: It is strange: when evaluating root.isDirectory(), I am getting false. And I'm doing the very same calling schema as you do.

Comment: @RomanRdgz On the first call? Since it is using recursion, root.isDirectory() get called several times, on both nested files and directories. If it does be on the first call, what does root.exists() return?

Comment: It is being called just a single time: The root I am giving to the calling instruction is getting exists() = false too, but I checked again the path and it is correct. It must exist! Should be a problem using an UNIX filesystem with this code?

Comment: Ok forget it, I was obviously putting the wrong path. Your code works like charm! thanks!